# MissingWebPart Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.SearchApplicationShortcutsList

Tags: web-part, search, central-administration

In Sharepoint Health Analyzer I've got a few errors for Missing WebParts in Search (`SearchApplicationShortcutsList, FarmSystemStatus, FarmSearchApplicationList, SearchTopologyOverview, SearchApplicationSystemStatus)`

```
[MissingWebPart] WebPart class [8307a780-2546-f10b-551f-0e692d0fce39] (class [Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.SearchApplicationShortcutsList] from assembly [Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c]) is referenced [1] times in the database [SharePoint_AdminContent_6614eabd-d9b3-4ea7-a375-d4546bd428f6], but is not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this web part. One or more web parts are referenced in the database [SharePoint_AdminContent_6614eabd-d9b3-4ea7-a375-d4546bd428f6], but are not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature or solution which contains these web parts.
[MissingWebPart] WebPart class [63104819-a32f-88b6-ab4a-7bbd4fbb40e8] (class [Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.FarmSystemStatus] from assembly [Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c]) is referenced [1] times in the database [SharePoint_AdminContent_6614eabd-d9b3-4ea7-a375-d4546bd428f6], but is not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this web part. One or more web parts are referenced in the database [SharePoint_AdminContent_6614eabd-d9b3-4ea7-a375-d4546bd428f6], but are not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature or solution which contains these web parts.
[MissingWebPart] WebPart class [9328cc53-be2c-1cca-f310-ddd573a106a5] (class [Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.FarmSearchApplicationList] from assembly [Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c]) is referenced [1] times in the database [SharePoint_AdminContent_6614eabd-d9b3-4ea7-a375-d4546bd428f6], but is not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this web part. One or more web parts are referenced in the database [SharePoint_AdminContent_6614eabd-d9b3-4ea7-a375-d4546bd428f6], but are not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature or solution which contains these web parts.
[MissingWebPart] WebPart class [4465f30a-0604-4d3c-39fd-ecdb8812f3f3] (class [Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.SearchTopologyOverview] from assembly [Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c]) is referenced [1] times in the database [SharePoint_AdminContent_6614eabd-d9b3-4ea7-a375-d4546bd428f6], but is not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this web part. One or more web parts are referenced in the database [SharePoint_AdminContent_6614eabd-d9b3-4ea7-a375-d4546bd428f6], but are not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature or solution which contains these web parts.
[MissingWebPart] WebPart class [a9bc1035-cf56-e003-8a4d-fff0bb3da148] (class [Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.SearchApplicationSystemStatus] from assembly [Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c]) is referenced [1] times in the database [SharePoint_AdminContent_6614eabd-d9b3-4ea7-a375-d4546bd428f6], but is not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this web part. One or more web parts are referenced in the database [SharePoint_AdminContent_6614eabd-d9b3-4ea7-a375-d4546bd428f6], but are not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature or solution which contains these web parts.
```

I've found several blogs on google telling me to either refresh or change webparts in search administration / search service administration but nothing worked. Search is working fine though but I don't really like the error message in central admin.

anyone an idea what else I can try?

Comment: did you run the rule after editing the web parts on both pages?

Comment: one more thing, is  SharePoint Foundation Web Application service running on the search servers?

Comment: Hi, yes I run the rule after I did this and nothing changes and no, SharePoint Foundation Web Application service is not running on the search server. I'm trying to activate it and edit the webparts again. I'll keep you updated.

Comment: Hi, this was the solution. Thank you. Now the error is gone. Please answer the question so I can mark it as solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Waqas Sarwar mentioned, I had to start SharePoint Foundation Web Application on the Search Server to get rid of that message. When I stop it again and re-run the missing server side dependencies the error appears again. I now disabled the check, because I must not run two Web frontends because of some 3rd party licenses.